# change value in react with different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, module, jsx

So I have this react file structure

```
app/
  |- assets/
  |   |-pages/
  |   |   |-desktop.jsx
  |   |   |-mobile.jsx
  |   |-components.jsx
  |-index.jsx
```

In the index.jsx I require desktop.jsx in desktop.jsx I require components.jsx but there is a part in components.jsx that needs to change the state in a index.jsx class.

so its like this:

`index.jsx -> desktop.jsx -> components.jsx`

so how do I change the state of a class in index.jsx with a function that is in components.jsx

thanks for helping!

Comment: The easiest way would be to pass down a function from `index.jsx` to `desktop.jsx` then to `components.jsx` via the props. Call that in `components.jsx` and then the function can change the state which will propagate down.

Comment: Read [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the React documentation.

Comment: Yes @Joe I understand that but how does that part work that i can communicate from components.jsx to index.jsx?

Comment: @JoeClay yeah I understand those basics but the problem is over multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React, the thing to remember is **props down, events up**. This means to pass values from a parent component to a child, do it via props; to pass values from a child back to a parent, use an event.

In your case, you have multiple "layers" of components, so you'll have to do it in multiple steps. For example:

```
<Index val="the value to pass" />
```

Somewhere in the Index component `render` method, you have the following line:

```
<Desktop val={this.props.val} />
```

Thus, the original value is now accessible in the Desktop component. And like the Index component, the Desktop component `render` method includes:

```
<Components val={this.props.val} />
```

To pass the value back up the chain of components requires events and event handlers. For example:

Imagine that the Index component has a method `onValChange` which handles a change to the value. Then we render the child components like this:

```
// in the index component, a change will call the index component
// onValChange method
<Desktop val={this.props.val} onValChange={this.onValChange} />

// in the desktop component, a change will call the props.onValChange
// method (which is the same one passed in the line above)
<Component val={this.props.val} onValChange={this.props.onValChange} />
```